# Problem creating an .IPA from VS 2019 in macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, xamarin

I updated my mac yesterday to macOS Catalina, Xcode 11.2 (11B52) and now VS 2019 gives me error when trying to create the .IPA to be uploaded to the app store.

Any ides would be really appreciated.

I get this error:

> Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with an unsupported version of
>   Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make
>   sure you are using the GM version of Xcode 10.1 and the SDK for iOS
>   12.1 and watchOS 5.1, Xcode 7.1 and the SDK for tvOS 9, or Xcode 6 and the SDK for macOS 10.9 or later. If you are using an Xcode beta
>   version to test your app, make sure you are using the latest supported
>   version. For more information about supported beta versions, view the
>   App Store Connect What's New page
>   (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/).

This is the detailed VS info
=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.3.7 (build 1)
Installation UUID: 6559d959-472c-4c78-b6a7-42917228eb05
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)

```
Package version: 604000208
```

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43) (64-bit)
    Package version: 604000208

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.3.0.6192

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.0.100
    2.1.701
    2.1.700
    2.1.505
    2.1.504
    2.1.302
    2.1.301
    2.1.4
    2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.0.0
    2.1.13
    2.1.12
    2.1.11
    2.1.9
    2.1.8
    2.1.2
    2.1.1
    2.0.5
    2.0.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.12.29
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 11.2 (15526)
Build 11B52

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 6.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: e3c2b406d
Branch: xcode11.2
Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:07-0400

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 13.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: e3c2b406d
Branch: xcode11.2
Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:08-0400

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.3.0.256
Hash: 8a223bfd7
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-11-01 21:02:02 UTC

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 10.0.6.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/c407838
Android SDK: /Users/laceup/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        5.0 (API level 21)
        5.1 (API level 22)
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.4
SDK Build Tools Version: 28.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: mono/mono/2019-06@476d72b9e32
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58
LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94
LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3fd
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333

=== Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===

Java SDK: /Users/laceup/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 1.4.0.65
Hash: c33b107
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-10-10 12:15:44 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 1.2.0.116
Hash: d2b2af0
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-10-10 12:16:06 UTC

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 803070001
Git revision: 9245c93bbca71766f0150b84e30dd42c394bd259
Build date: 2019-11-04 21:08:08+00
Build branch: release-8.3
Xamarin extensions: ea50d7eae9677fbbd7ff7578a7d1429b9946a728

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.1
Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0
    Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7349

Answer (score 2):

**As Marc_Alx states in the comment, you can get Xcode 11.2.1 GM directly from developer.apple.com if your App Store does not yet list this release.**

I was having the same issue. After trying multiple times to upload the app anyhow, I finally received a different message during the process:

> WARNING ITMS-90703: "Deprecated Xcode Build. Due to resolved app
>   archives issues, we have deprecated Xcode 11.2 on November 5, 2019.
>   Download Xcode 11.2.1 or newer, rebuild your app and resubmit."

Our current Xcode was just deprecated in the last hour...

Comment: Damn, I validated a build earlier today, then spent hours working on screenshots and app previews, and now just as I'm about to submit they deprecate the Xcode build so I get to download nearly 8GB just to upload to the app store. Thanks for nothing Apple ◔_◔

Comment: As a fix, you can get Xcode 11.2.1 GM directly from developer.apple.com (even if not released on the store)